# Wpf application on .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serial-port, windows-xp-sp3

I'm in face on the following problem: An application developed on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 in .NET 4.5, needs to work in Window XP Platforms. I'm rebuild the software using .NET 4.0 and make some modifications to add compatibility, but when i click in a button the app crash and don't show a clear error message and the Trace resource don't log anything. On application start i had a little window that ask user to put your name, and this feature works fine. Anybody have any suggestion of what can i do ?

**EDIT 1:**

The follow code is the root of problems, this code was compiled using .NET 4.0:

**SerialManager.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using TestSat;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestSat.DataModel
{
  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
    public class SerialManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region Events

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

      /*  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
        public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute
        {
        }*/

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="field"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Fields

        private static SerialPort PortaSerial;
        private ObservableCollection<String> mPorts;
        private String mSelectedPort;
        private int mBaudRate = 115200;
        private int mDataBits = 8;

        #endregion

        #region Public Fields
        public StringBuilder logText;
        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<String> COMPorts
        {
            get { return mPorts; }
            set { SetField(ref mPorts, value); }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public String TextoLog
        {
            get { return logText.ToString(); }
            set
            {

                if (logText.Length >= logText.MaxCapacity)
                {
                    logText.Clear();;

                    logText.Append(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    logText.Append(value);
                    //MainWindow.last = value;
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("TextoLog");
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public String SelectedPort
        {
            get { return mSelectedPort; }
            set {SetField(ref mSelectedPort, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Construtors

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public SerialManager()
        {
            InitComponents();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void InitComponents()
        {
            RefreshPorts();

            /*Initialize the log variable*/
            logText = new StringBuilder();

            /* Update selected port */
            SelectedPort = COMPorts.Count > 0 ? COMPorts[0] : "";


        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void RefreshPorts()
        {
            // Update ports
            string[] pPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            // Sort alphabetically
            Array.Sort(pPorts);
            // Sort by string length
            Array.Sort(pPorts, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));

            // Create collection
            COMPorts = new ObservableCollection<string>(pPorts);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mSelectedPort"></param>
        public void ConnectSerial(String mSelectedPort)
        {
            PortaSerial = new SerialPort();
            PortaSerial.PortName = mSelectedPort;
            PortaSerial.BaudRate = mBaudRate;
            PortaSerial.Parity = Parity.None;
            PortaSerial.DataBits = mDataBits;
            PortaSerial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            PortaSerial.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            PortaSerial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            Trace.WriteLine("DataReceived definida");
            try
            {
                PortaSerial.Open();
            }
            catch (SystemException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A porta serial esta sendo usada em outra aplicação.", "Erro", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                throw new SystemException();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>

        public void DesconnectSerial()
        {
            if (PortaSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                PortaSerial.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void writeSerial(String text)
        {
            if (PortaSerial.IsOpen)
            {
                if (text.Length > 0)
                {
                    /* char[] array = text.ToCharArray(0,text.Length);
                     foreach(char ch in array)
                     {
                         PortaSerial.Write(ch.ToString());
                         Thread.Sleep(50); 

                     }*/
                    PortaSerial.WriteLine(text);
                }
                else
                {
                    PortaSerial.WriteLine("");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Porta serial não esta aberta.", "Erro", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                Console.WriteLine("Porta serial não esta aberta");
            }


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsOpen()
        {
            return PortaSerial.IsOpen;
        } 


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            MainWindow.StartRawData = true;
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            TextoLog = indata;

          /*Omited code only logical operation*/

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

If i don't do any instance or reference to serial port the applications don't crashes. Exist a way to force this part of code compiled by .NET 3.5? Or exist another suggestion of solution for this problem?

Comment: If you have the source, you should add more error logging, or attach a remote debugger. Given the information you've provided, its going to be difficult for anybody to suggest what to do. .NET 4 WPF applications are compatible with Windows XP, so there is something you are doing that's incompatible in the code (which you didn't provide).

Comment: Look in the windows application event log by running eventvwr.exe

Comment: Windows XP is unsupported, **even by Microsoft**, why do you care about that?

Comment: @HighCore: unsupported or not, XP is in a lot of places.  Usually businesses that don't want to spend a few million in licensing for existing computers that should have been retired 5 years ago.

Comment: Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never optional.  Be sure to log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString() so you can tell why it failed.

Comment: Is .NET 4.0 even supported by Windows XP?  I was under the impression that XP required .NET 3.5.

Comment: I double-checked on whether XP is supported by .NET 4.0.  It is, but not for the Starter, Media Center or Tablet editions.  You aren't running one of those, are you?

Comment: The problem is in the log, because i don't know when starts the trace. I put in the first line of event on click of a button but nothing is captured. The window loads normally the error occurs in any button click. @JeffPrince , my aplication only use the serial port, the rest of aplications is only text box and buttons.

Comment: I isolate the all serialport code interactions and the application don't crash anymore. This same applications runs perfectly in Windows 7 environment . I tried to compile the application using .NET 3.5 but don't worked.  Anybody have a suggestion to right configure the serial port for use on window XP. If needed I can post the utilized code for analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.asp , Issue 8. Installing the .NET 4.0 update the problems don't occured anymore.